# How to enable setCalendarViewShown or disable calendar in datepicker post API 24

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a project where I use datepicker for the user to confirm a date

When the user selects confirm I wish to disable the datepicker so that they can't use it again

Unfortunatelly when I do something like this:

```
((DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datepicker)).enabled = false;
```

only the spinner part gets disabled while the calendar can still be touched and used to alter the spinner

the only solution I found is using setCalendarViewShown(false) when the user confirms and then disabling the picker

unfortunatelly this seems to be deprecated so I wish to find some way to replace it

So my question is this

Is there a way to programmatically either disable ALL parts of the DatePicker or hide the calendar?

I know it can be done through xml but I wish to use it in code

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the datepicker with:

```
datepicker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

An option that you can choose to disabled all dates less one, is combine this two lines.

```
datepicker.setMinDate
datepicker.setMaxDate
```

So after the user pick one date, set the date like the min and the max of the calendar, and with this way, the user will not be able to choose a new one.

Something like:

```
datepicker.setMinDate(theDatePickedByUser)
datepicker.setMaxDate(theDatePickedByUser)
```

It should work...

Comment: I don't wish to hide the whole datepicker, my problem is that even when I disable the datepicker, the user can still alter the selected date using the calendar

Comment: Yeah that's what I went with too

Comment: Nice =), happy to help.